# Redirects HTTPS to HTTP via cPanel

Tags: http, redirect, https, cpanel

How could I redirect HTTPS to HTTP via cPanel ? I have been trying to redirect it from .htaccess but it still not work.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have an active SSL you may need to do the .htaccess redirect this way

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some specific cases when you want to redirect particular URL or a single website to be opened through HTTP instead of HTTPS. For that purpose you should add the following rewrite rule in your .htaccess file:

RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =https
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

This will redirect your https to http.